# SQLite database corruption on embbeded system

Tags: c, sqlite, embedded-linux, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I'm testing the integrity of an SQLite database when a power outage occur on a beaglebone embedded Linux system using an eMMC.

I configured the database with

```
PRAGMA synchronous = FULL
PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL
```

and keep writing in the database while the power is cut by a relay. The test runs automatically for a couple of hours.

After a while, the database gets corrupted with the following errors:

integrity_check: *** in database main ***
Page 50861: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
On tree page 50820 cell 83: Child page depth differs
Page 50862: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50863: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50864: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50865: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50866: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50867: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50868: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50869: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50870: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50871: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50872: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 50873: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
On tree page 50820 cell 96: Child page depth differs

I've read the following articles about SQLite:

https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

What can I do to prevent database corruption?

If it's not feasible, what are my options since I don't care about loosing some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite allows for corruption during power outages, but only in those sectors that are being written.

The flash chip that you're using can corrupt lots of unrelated sectors.
This is impossible to detect; It is not possible to prevent data loss with this hardware.

Comment: Using an ext3 partition solved my database corruption problem. But your're right that the flash chip can also corrupt unrelated sectors.